# Text-background Stretched Across Container

Tags: html, css, background, styles, containers

This is probably an easy question. I have header text that has a background color. The background color stops when the text stops. I want the background to fill the entire length of the container.

```
<body>

 <div class="container">
   <p><span style="color:#ffffff; font-size:30px; background-color:#e12025;">I want the background-   color stretched across the container</span>
 </div>

</body>
```

css:

```
body {
background-color:#e12025;
align:center;
font-family:sans-serif;
color:#000000;
font-size:28px;
}

.container {
background-color:#ffffff;
position:relative;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:1785px;
width:900px;
border-style:none;
padding:10px;
}
```

Here's an example: [http://mm2.co/background-color](http://mm2.co/background-color/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want everything in the container to 'stretch' across the container, remove the padding in the container:

```
.container {
    padding:10px; /* remove this */
}
```

If you still want to keep the top/bottom padding in the container, do this instead:

```
   .container {
        padding:10px 0px; /* add the 0px */
   }
```

Also, you are going to want to make the display of the span paragraph - **block**.

Add/change to this:

`<span style="display:block;">text here..</span>`

Answer (score 0):

um...

```
.container {
    display: block;
}
```

?